# is it possible to have two foreign keys for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I am comfortable coding in T-SQL but new to db design. I have

1. a table of departments with PK_Department
2. a table of loinc codes/test info with PK_Loinc
3. a (differently structured) table of non-loinc codes/test info with PK_nonLoinc.

I want to set up a one-to-one relationship between (PK_Department) <--> (PK_Loinc OR PK_nonLoinc)

Is there a way to setup this relationship using two FK's in T-SQL?

If not, I guess I could setup a table LoincAndNonLoincCodes with three columns, `PK_union, PK_Loinc and FK_nonLoinc -- where (FK_Loinc is filled ExclusiveOR FK_nonLoinc is filled)` and then setup a table linking `FK_UNION` with `FK_Department` but ideally I would be able to do this without creating another table.

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I know the answer is no, you can't have two FKs for one column.  Another alternative to the extra table might be an extra column.  In the department table, put in FK_Loinc and FK_nonLoinc and only fill one or the other.  It depends on how strict the database rules have to be though (you could add triggers to prevent both from being filled, but that is a lot of effort).

Comment: You seem to have deleted you original question? If I understand correctly, for Loinc you need only `{LoincID}` for the key, while for local you would need `{LocalID, Verbose}` for the key?

Comment: @DamirSudarevic that is correct. i did not delete "original" post though. what do you mean?

Comment: @akh2103, I saw the story about Loinc having different possible `Verbose` like `LabA` and `Lab_A` somewhere? .. and how tests with codes are to be routed to departments ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you're trying to associate each department with a given Observation (i.e. the 'O' in LOINC).

The problem isn't with the Department object but rather the 'Observation' object.  The Observation is a type hierarchy.  An abstract Observation can be a concrete Non-LOINC Observation or a concrete LOINC Observation.  The relational model isn't good at modelling type hierarchies.  There are 3 options for modelling the Observation:

1. Use one Observation table with both LOINC and non-LOINC codes in it.  In which case the PK would be a composite key of the Type and Code attributes and contain all attributes of both LOINC and non-LOINC codes.  Then you can have a 1:1 FK to this Observation table.
2. One table for non-LOINC codes and one table for LOINC code.  In this case, you have the problem as you've stated in your question.
3. Three tables.  One for Observation and one for non LOINC Observations and one for LOINC Observations.  Then have a 1:1 FK to the Observation table.

This is classic illustration of the object/relational impedance mismatch problem.

Comment: I'd go with option number 3. Create a parent table to both Loinc and nonLoinc tables. This table does not need to have any other columns except PK, but you could also put a flag column to tell you whatever row is Loinc/nonLoinc. So now both Loinc and NonLoinc should reference the new table from their PK to new table's PK and Department table can easily have FK to new parent table (and thus referencing both child tables).